# WGSL throws parsing error on seemingly correct code

Tags: wgpu-rs, wgsl

I have a storage texture which I (try to) write to in a compute shader. Then in the fragment shader I am trying to read from that storage texture using `textureLoad`, but I am getting this error and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong:

```rs
Caused by:
    In Device::create_shader_module
      note: label = `shader.wgsl`
    
Shader 'shader.wgsl' parsing error: wrong number of arguments: expected 3, found 3
   ┌─ wgsl:25:17
   │
25 │     let color = textureLoad(input, coords.xy, 1u);
   │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ wrong number of arguments


    wrong number of arguments: expected 3, found 3
```

This is the compute shader:

```rs
@group(0) @binding(0)
var input: texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm, read_write>;

struct VertexInput {
    @location(0) position: vec3<f32>,
    @location(1) color: vec3<f32>,
};

struct VertexOutput {
    @builtin(position) clip_position: vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) color: vec3<f32>,
}

@vertex
fn vs_main(model: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    out.color = model.color;
    out.clip_position = vec4<f32>(model.position, 1.0);
    return out;
}

@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    let coordinates = vec2<u32>(in.clip_position.xy);
    let color = textureLoad(input, coordinates, 0u);
    return color;
}
```

This is the vertex/fragment shader code:

```rs
@group(0) @binding(0)
var input: texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm, read_write>;

struct VertexInput {
    @location(0) position: vec3<f32>,
    @location(1) color: vec3<f32>,
};

struct VertexOutput {
    @builtin(position) clip_position: vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) color: vec3<f32>,
}

@vertex
fn vs_main(model: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    out.color = model.color;
    out.clip_position = vec4<f32>(model.position, 1.0);
    return out;
}

@fragment
fn fs_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    let coordinates = vec2<u32>(in.clip_position.xy);
    let color = textureLoad(input, coordinates, 0u);
    return color;
}
```

I tried reading through the documentation and it doesn't seem like I'm doing something wrong which breaks the shader like this.

I basically created a texture and passed the texture view into both the bind group for the compute and render pipeline. Is it even possible to use the same texture for this or do I need to copy it to another texture after the compute shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overload of [`textureLoad`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#textureload) accepting an argument of type [`texture_storage_2d`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#type-texture_storage_2d) (as first parameter) in the official [WGSL Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/).

Thats because baseline wgpu does not support read and write storage textures. However as stated [here](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/issues/2735#issuecomment-1546908165) it is possible to

> read from a texture by binding it as a normal texture (not a storage texture) and then using `textureLoad` on it

There has also been this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76247496/4593433) before.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that could be the problem.
So I create a normal texture_2d, add it as a bindgroup to both the compute and render pipeline and should then be able to write to it in the compute shader and read from in the fragment shader. 
Did I understand you correctly?
And what are the use cases of storage textures then?

Comment: So I just tried it out and got it to actually run.   
I declared the usage of the texture in the texturedescriptor as `STORAGA_TEXTURE | TEXTURE_BINDING` and then defined it as a storage texture in the compute bindgroup layout and as a texture in the render bindgroup layout.   
Does that make sense? Because it's just giving me a black window right now.

Comment: I think you did not fully understand the answer correctly. Your second comment sounds to me like you did try to write to a normal texture in the compute shader. However you can only write to `Storage Texture` and `Storaga Buffer` in compute stages. See here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599251/wgpu-compute-write-direct-to-surface-texture-view

Comment: As I said I tried to create the texture as storage texture **and** texture binding and specified it as storage texture or normal texture in the comptue / render bind group layout respectively. I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/LordRobin1/c9c46e9cadb8354b6c029be17aecbbc9) so you can take a look at what I am doing if you have the time to do so.

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help much more to find out what the issue is now, instead of a gist missing code required to actually run it.

Comment: I updated the gist to contain everything that is needed to demonstrate the problem. I left it as a gist since it is still a lot of code.

Comment: Looks much better now, I'll see when I can take a look, since I'm curious what the problem is now...